# Python, scikit, regression error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

In Python, I'm trying to run a regression. I have created my train/test sets and they are OK. The code I'm using is

```
linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and I get the error: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 11]

I have checked multiple times that both `X_train` and `y_train` are arrays of length 11

Comment: sounds like X_train is probably a list containing a list with 11 elements.  If your last line were actually true, you wouldn't be having this problem.  Try: `linreg.fit(X_train[0], y_train)`

Comment: I found the answer: y's were just vectors, i.e. (dim,) arrays and of course x's were also (dim,). Scikit expects (dim,1) array for x's.So I reshaped. I will try your solution. Thanks!